# Make Discord Bot Send Regular Messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a bot that sends automatic messages every 4 hours, but for some reason it doesn't work. I looked all over the google and stack overflow but none of the answers could help me. Did discord change the way bots send messages ?

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def messages():
  channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
  response = "test"
  await channel.send(response)

messages.start()
```

If I try to run this code it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

any help will be appreciated and thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Client.loop.create_task()` you can create a repeating task and
I added `client.wait_until_ready()` to wait until the bot starts and with `asyncio.sleep(seconds)`The Bot will wait for 4 hours.

```
async def message_loop():
await client.wait_until_ready()

while not client.is_closed():
    #your code here
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    response = "test"
    await channel.send(response)

    await asyncio.sleep(60*60*4)#seconds*minute*hour
client.loop.create_task(message_loop())
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'.  For some reason bot can't get channel properly, but I even looked into documentation for get_channel function and passed id as an integer, but it's still gives same error, i am so confused why

Comment: I managed to fix it, instead of bot.get_channel(channel_id), i used client.get_channel(id=channel_id). Thank you very much for your help, I still used your code to make it recurring

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it on my own. Instead of channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) get id from the client by using channel = client.get_channel(id=channel_id)

```
async def messages():
  await client.wait_until_ready()
  while not client.is_closed():
    channel = client.get_channel(id=channel_id)
    response = "test"
    await channel.send(response)

    await asyncio.sleep(60*60*4)
client.loop.create_task(messages())
```